# How to add stylish break lines for text like '___ 'and '-' with CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm attaching a few example images to show what I mean.

For now what I was doing is adding extra div inside HTML and styling it in CSS with border-bottom, width and color codes, after that centering it within text with margin and padding. Is here are more effective way of doing it?

How you approach designs like this?

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

[image: Example 3]

Comment: This seems like a opinion based question and this is against the StackOverflow guideline.

Comment: You can use `:before` and `:after` in CSS. See this https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-add-lines-before-and-after-heading-text.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pseudo selectors like this:

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

h1:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 2px;
  background: blue;
  left: 10%;
  bottom : -10%;
}
```

```html
<h1>something here</h1>
```

```css
h1:before{
content:"- ";
color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>something else</h1>
```

or if you have a list, you can take advantage of `list-style-type: '-'`:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: '- ';
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
</ul>
```